# Beijing to Boston, layover in Japan. Arrive in Haneda and leave from Narita. How about my check-in luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, luggage, japan

I may need to layover in Japan for my trip from Beijing to Boston. Also I need to change airports from Haneda airport to Narita airport. The layover is about 5 hours 15 minutes. Do I need to take care of my check-in luggage?

Usually we don't need to handle the check-in luggage for stopovers. How about this one? They are in different airports! If you have experience in person, please share with us.

No visa will be needed for this transit as I read from other posts, right?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

One trip, one ticket. I am Chinese with a US green card.

[image]

Comment: The standard question: Is this all on one ticket? Or do you have two separate bookings?

Comment: Don't know about the specific situation in Tokyo, but other cities with multiple airports I know of, if you switch to a different airport you have to reclaim your luggage and check-it back in at the other airport. But if you gave us more details (the airline(s) involved and whether this is on a single booking) that may help.

Comment: As for the visa, you should probably include your nationality as this may have an influence.

Comment: Indeed nationality has influence, Chinese need transfer visa to leave Haneda airport.

Comment: Maybe they will give you a Shore Pass, but I've heard horror stories of Shore Passes not granted. To be safe do apply for a transit visa.

Comment: Shore Pass can be used in single prefecture, and Haneda is located in Tokyo prefecture while Narita is in Chiba prefecture.

Answer (score 4):

- Visa absolutely needed.
- I don't think they will transport your luggage to NRT, so you'll have to take it and go through customs with it. But ask JAL by giving them a call.
- The most convenient option is probably just cancel this flight (if you can) and book one that doesn't require an inter-airport transfer :-)